# Application Architecture & BizTalk

Tags: wcf, architecture, console-application, biztalk, biztalk-2010

**Application Setup**
I have created a internal WCF service that calls a RESTful service on the net and gets JSON data back from it. I call the internal WCF once a day using a console application that I run using a scheduled job.

My question is since we will be moving to BizTalk 2010 in the future to do these sort of things, Is it better to keep the GET request code in the WCF service or eliminate the WCF service altogether and put the code directly in the console app? I was thinking in the future I could just have BizTalk call the WCF service instead of BizTalk running a console app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to consume the RESTful service in your BizTalk flow.
In that way, the port will send and get the messages and you will be able to investigate them in case of an error. You don't need another "tunnel" just for consuming that RESTful service.

You can check here how it gets done:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2474.invoke-restful-web-services-with-biztalk-server-2010.aspx#ReST_what